# ios and Facebook integration: where can I find docs or tuts on "Like Button" API?

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook-graph-api

I have downloaded the latest FacebookSDK for IOS and have the "post to your wall" function working (did this just to get my feet wet).

However, what I really need is documentation or tutorials on getting a like button for my client.  Can't seem to find any.  Can anyone point me in the right direction ??? I would like the users for the client to be able to press "like" for facebook or "follow" for twitter.

-Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a set of like code on github yesterday. Search for "FacebookLikeView". The downloadable code set has a demo app included.

Comment: Thanks, good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

this should not work...
since inside the source he use FBdialog which is no longer available inside the Facebook SDK3.1 ...
i am afraid you would have to satisfy using this -> http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/
or try something else and maybe even solve a lot of problems for a lot of people if u could do it differently